# AWS S3 trouble with anchor in filename #

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have some filenames stored with the # symbol. If I send a GET request to retrieve them I am running into problems as I believe GET requests are cut off at anchors within the path?

ex:

```
s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/my_file.jpg
```

vs: my browser stops looking at the #

```
s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/my_other_#file.jpg
```

is there a way to retrieve the file or will I have to change filenames so they do not contain #'s?

Answer (score 2):

You need to encode your path as URL which would replace # with %23.

Check out this for URL encoding. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

In JavaScript you can use `encodeURI()` to get it encoded. 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp